# javafx ComboBox with cellfactory does not display selected item

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, observablelist

I have a small proof of concept app which contains 6 `Labels` a `ComboBox` and a `Button`, all created using SceneBuilder.

By clicking the `Button`, the app makes a Json api call to return a list of countries and their related details (apla2code, apla3code, name etc). I created a `CountryDetails` object which holds 3 `String` elements. I use that to return an array of the `CountryDetails` which I then load into an array of `ObserbavleList`. I then apply that to a `ComboBox` and I load the `CountryDetails` elements into 3 labels each time an item is selected in the `ComboBox`. The All of this works fine (although there is probably a much better way of doing this).

The problem I am having is that the `ComboBox` is not displaying the selected item and I cannot figure out how to correct this. The image below shows what the issue is.

The code which makes the api call is as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetCountries {

    public CountryDetails[] getDetails() {

        String inputLine            = "";
        StringBuilder jsonString    = new StringBuilder();

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(inputLine);
            }
            urlConnection.getInputStream().close();

        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        Countries[] countries = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString.toString(), Countries[].class);

        CountryDetails[] countryDetails = new CountryDetails[countries.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){

            countryDetails[i] = new CountryDetails(
                    countries[i].getAlpha2Code(),
                    countries[i].getAlpha3Code(),
                    countries[i].getName()
            );
        }
        return countryDetails;
    }
}
```

The code for the `CountryDetails` object is as follows:

```
public class CountryDetails {

    private String alpha2Code;
    private String alpha3Code;
    private String name;

    public CountryDetails(String strAlpha2Code, String strAlpha3Code, String strName) {
        this.alpha2Code = strAlpha2Code;
        this.alpha3Code = strAlpha3Code;
        this.name = strName;
    }

    public String getAlpha2Code() { return alpha2Code; }

    public void setAlpha2Code(String alpha2Code) { this.alpha2Code = alpha2Code; }

    public String getAlpha3Code() { return alpha3Code; }

    public void setAlpha3Code(String alpha3Code) { this.alpha3Code = alpha3Code; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name; }
}
```

The code which loads the `ObservableList` is as follows:

```
GetCountries countries = new GetCountries();

        CountryDetails[] countryDetails = countries.getDetails();

        for (CountryDetails countryDetail : countryDetails) {
            countriesObservableList.add(new CountryDetails(
                    countryDetail.getAlpha2Code(),
                    countryDetail.getAlpha3Code(),
                    countryDetail.getName())
            );
        }
```

The code which loads the `ComboBox` and displays the elements in the `Labels` is as follows:

```
    cbCountryList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<CountryDetails>, ListCell<CountryDetails>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<CountryDetails> call(ListView<CountryDetails> p) {
                return new ListCell<CountryDetails>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(CountryDetails item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty || (item == null) || (item.getName() == null)) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            setText(item.getName());
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

    public void comboAction(ActionEvent event) {
        lblAlpha2Code.setText(cbCountryList.getValue().getAlpha2Code());
        lblAlpha3Code.setText(cbCountryList.getValue().getAlpha3Code());
        lblCountryName.setText(cbCountryList.getValue().getName());
    }
```

Below is the image of the app:

[image]

Comment: Set the [`ComboBox#buttonCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#buttonCellProperty) to an instance returned by your custom cell factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am having is that the ComboBox is not displaying the selected item and I cannot figure out how to correct this.

You need to set a [StringConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html) for your `cbCountryList`.

```
cbCountryList.setConverter(new StringConverter<CountryDetails>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(CountryDetails object) {
        return object.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public CountryDetails fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

> The All of this works fine (although there is probably a much better way of doing this).

You may consider updating the following things,

- Asynchronous call for HTTP request and load items
- You can cache your `fetched-country` list as you're calling every time when the button gets triggered. You can make a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object for `GetCountries`.

**Modified `GetCountries` class**,

It caches the countries list and uses the cached data for multiple requests,

```
 public static class GetCountries {

    private static final String API_URL = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";
    private static CountryDetails[] countryDetails;

    public static CountryDetails[] getDetails() {

        //uses cached countryDetails once it gets loaded
        if (countryDetails != null) {
            return countryDetails;
        }

        StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(API_URL);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpMethod.GET.name());

            String inputLine = "";

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(inputLine);
            }
            urlConnection.getInputStream().close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        Countries[] countries = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString.toString(), Countries[].class);

        countryDetails = new CountryDetails[countries.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            countryDetails[i] = new CountryDetails(
                    countries[i].getAlpha2Code(),
                    countries[i].getAlpha3Code(),
                    countries[i].getName()
            );
        }
        return countryDetails;
    }
}
```

Use [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to fetch your countries asynchronously,

```
Task<CountryDetails[]> fetchCountryTask = new Task<CountryDetails[]>() {
    @Override
    protected CountryDetails[] call() throws Exception {
        return GetCountries.getDetails();
    }
};

fetchButton.setOnAction(event -> new Thread(fetchCountryTask).start());

fetchCountryTask.setOnRunning(event -> cbCountryList.setDisable(true));

fetchCountryTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    cbCountryList.getItems().addAll(fetchCountryTask.getValue());
    cbCountryList.setDisable(false);
});
```

Comment: Sekhar Rai: Thanks for that. The `StringConverter` works a treat. As for the Asynchronous call and the caching, This is just a proof of concept and will ultimately form part of a config wizard for a larger application. The list will only be generated once when the wizard loads and will not be called again. However, this will definitely be useful for other parts of the application which will need to access similar returned Json data more frequently and in the same session.